# WPF Style selectors on TargetType specifying nested target types

Tags: css, wpf, xaml, css-selectors

How would I specify, for example all Paragraph tags inside a Table (excluding those outside the table) in a FlowDocument. I was expecting something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Table">
    <Style TargetType="Paragraph">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Style>
</Style>
```

However nested styles are not allowed like that.

The equivilent to what I want to achieve in CSS would be something like:

```
Table Paragraph {margin:0}
```

So all paragraph tags within the scope of the table would have a margin of 0. Is this possible in WPF (in the XAML markup part)? Any good source on complex WPF style selectors would also be appreciated.

I could write code to do it, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I would upvote this question if the better answer was accepted.

Comment: @Guge Well, even though it is a better answer, I don't think it would be elegant to un-accept the previous answer. It did answer my question and the better one came half a year later. It will be voted up anyway so why should I discredit points from the original answerer? Just vote the better answer up (I also gave it an up-vote myself) and it will eventually end up at the top. Helping out (or attempting to) in a timely fashion also deserves points and I don't believe that taking back a reward after half a year would be grateful, rewarding or motivating.

Comment: Not even if the first answer is wrong?

Comment: @LouisSomers I appreciate the thought but... You're intentionally hiding a good answer below a bad one. The goal of this site isn't to get rep (or it shouldn't be) it's to create a knowledge base that's useful to others. Plus... If you're worried about rep, Sheridan's in the 40 thousands and Nate's in double digits. I came here looking for an answer and almost missed it. Luckily I scrolled down enough to see the correct one, but that's what prompted this comment in the first place. Anyway, +1 for asking the question and saving me time, thanks

Comment: Ok, you guys have a point. I accepted the correct answer. I thought that it would end up on top any way when it had enough up-votes, but apparently that's not the case. It does feel a bit unloyal, or anti principle, to take something back after granting just because something better comes along later. Any way, in this case I guess it is right to do so rather than leading others on the wrong track.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is actually possible to do a kind of style nesting similar to CSS by creating a style and then including one or more styles inside the Style.Resources property like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="Table">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Paragraph">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

This style will be applied to all Tables in scope and the nested Paragraph style will be applied to all Paragraphs *inside* those tables, but not Paragraphs that are outside of Tables. That's because putting things inside the Resources property basically injects them into the visibility scope of all child objects.

You could also technically do multiple levels of nesting like this to color Hyperlinks green that are only inside of Paragraphs, that are only inside of Tables:

```
    <Style TargetType="Table">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Paragraph">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

Comment: This is a much better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for you, WPF doesn't work quite like CSS. You can still get the effect that you want, just not quite as simply. You'd need to name the `Style` and apply it whichever `Paragraph` elements that you wanted to affect manually:

```
<Style x:Key="NoSPaceParagraph" TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
</Style>
```

...

```
<Paragraph Style="{StaticResource NoSPaceParagraph}">
    ....
</Paragraph>
```

Comment: Ok then I'll have to live with it. I'll just statically assign `Margin="0"` since that's shorter than applying a style and it's the only thing I want for now.